# momentjs and null dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following code that is linked to a date slider, i've done a bit of digging and can find many items on validation but not on returning null data.

as this project was inherited i have no fallback documents to review internally and i'm new(ish) to coding javascript.

is anyone able to advise me if moment.js can also allow the return of null data as it would seem historically the table where the data is queried never contained nulls but legitimately does now (great)

thanks for any hints tips on controlling this in advance

```
initializeDateSlider: function(minDate, maxDate, startDate, endDate, stepType, step) {
var interval = MapsLib.sliderInterval(stepType);

$('#minDate').html(minDate.format('MMM YYYY'));
$('#maxDate').html(maxDate.format('MMM YYYY'));
$('#startDate').html(startDate.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
$('#endDate').html(endDate.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
$('#date-range').slider({
range: true,
step: step,
values: [ Math.floor((startDate.valueOf() - minDate.valueOf()) / interval),
Math.floor((maxDate.valueOf() - minDate.valueOf()) / interval) ],
  max: Math.floor((maxDate.valueOf() - minDate.valueOf()) / interval),
  slide: function(event, ui) {
$('#startDate').html(minDate.clone().add(stepType, ui.values[0]).format('DD MMM YYYY'));
$('#endDate').html(minDate.clone().add(stepType, ui.values[1]).format('DD MMM YYYY'));
  },
```

Comment: You could use a guard to supply a default value: `startDate.valueOf() || 12345` or ternary: `startDate.valueOf() === null ? 12345 : startDate.valueOf()`. If that's not what you're asking, please clarify!

Comment: the min and max are defined - min being Sep 21 2006 and max being today... its more about taking the start and end date selected by the user and adding in those that have a null date - thanks for your quick reply which may help me on something else...